# Из XML выбрать нужные данные с приоритетом

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, парсер

Есть упрощенный вариант xml:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <eissn>12-12</eissn>
    </item>
    <item>
        <eissn>11-13</eissn>
        <issn>11-12</issn>
    </item>
    <item>
    </item>
</items>
```

Мне нужно извлечь все issn и eissn, но если ни того, ни другого нет, этой строки вообще не должно быть. А если есть и issn, и eissn, то в приоритете должен быть issn. Ожидаемый вариант:

```
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: 12-12
*****
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: 11-12
*****
#1105: Статья в журнале
*****
```

С этой функцией я получаю issn и eissn:

```
def get_issn_eissn(item) -> str:
    return item.find("issn") or item.find("eissn")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for item in root.select('item'):
     issn_eissn = get_issn_eissn(item)
        issn_eissn = '#963: ' + str(issn_eissn)
        issn_eissn = re.sub(r'\<.*?\>', '', issn_eissn)
        print(issn_eissn)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно выставить приоритет и если ничего нет, получить:

```
#1105: Статья в журнале
*****
```

Заранее благодарна за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение "в лоб":

```
def get_issn(item):
    x = item.find('issn') or item.find('eissn')
    return '#1105: Статья в журнале' + (f'\n#963: {x.text}' if x else '') + '\n*****'
```

---

```
In [17]: for item in root.select('item'):
    ...:     print(get_issn(item))
    ...:
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: 12-12
*****
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: 11-12
*****
#1105: Статья в журнале
*****
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Все сработало!!!